# why is this not opening the image?

Tags: jquery, html, css

my problem is that the image will not load on the page. it is in the folder, it is a .png, everything is right about it seemingly.... any ideas on how to get this to load the img?

```
header.masthead {
    text-align: center;
    color: white;
    background-image: url(..//HGlogo.png);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-attachment: scroll;
    background-position: center center;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover; 
}
```

Comment: `background-image: url("../HGlogo.png");` And can you provide your directory just to make sure

Comment: `background-image: url(..//HGlogo.png);`  need to be `background-image: url('../HGlogo.png');`

Comment: Maybe try it with url('./HGlogo') ? If the image is in the same folder, this may work.

Comment: that is right it is not loading?

Comment: @JosephBell  did you changed it to:-`background-image: url('../HGlogo.png');`? If not working try `background-image: url('../../HGlogo.png');`

Comment: @JosephBell please provide jsfiddle or code snippet so that we can help you

Comment: Please, show some HTML (see [mcve]).

Answer (score 4):

You have to put single / for creating a file location like

```
background-image: url('../img/HGlogo.png');
```

Suppose you have image at same folder or same location, don't use like this (../)

Answer (score 3):

Hard to say without seeing your folder structure, it could be, this:

`background-image: url('../images/HGlogo.png');` or 
`background-image: url('../HGlogo.png');`

Add a screenshot atleast showing the structure,

***Example:***[image]

**Remember:** (taken from [Quick Reminder About File Paths](https://css-tricks.com/quick-reminder-about-file-paths/))

> - Is the image in the same directory as the file referencing it?
> - Is the image in a directory **below**?
> - Is the image in a directory **above**?
>
> By "below" and "above", I mean subdirectories and parent directories.
>   Relative file paths give us a way to travel in both directions. Take a
>   look at my primitive example: [image]
>
> Here is all you need to know about relative file paths:
>
> - Starting with "/" returns to the root directory and starts there
> - Starting with "../" moves one directory backwards and starts there
> - Starting with "../../" moves two directories backwards and starts    there (and so on...)
> - To move forward, just start with the first subdirectory and keep    moving forward

Answer (score 1):

Path To image must be relative to your css file

lets assume your directory structure is like this =>

```
project
  --css
    --cssfile
  --img
    --HGlogo.png
```

then your code must be

```
background-image: url(../img/HGlogo.png)
```

Answer (score 0):

Triple check that the URL to the image is correct. Also

```
header.masthead
```

doesn't appear to have any dimensions specified, which would make it not appear. Also clear you browser cache, chrome debugger is your best friend. Otherwise everything else seems correct.

Comment: downloaded image how to add?

Comment: not sure what you mean, by you downloaded the image. Also you have an extra / in your path to the image.